# Laravel installation to set folder app/storage the write permission

Tags: php, permissions, laravel-4, webserver, storage

I'm trying to install Laravel as per the instructions on http://laravel.com/docs/quick

I need to set access permission and grant the web server write permissions to the app/storage directories.

How can i set the web server the write permissions?
Is it, just put the folder from read-only to write ? But like this nothing specifies that web server can write on folder app/storage

Comment: More info please! Are you on linux machine or using wamp/mamp on windows? Or you have your app located on server but you have access to cpanel only?

Comment: currently using WAMP server 2

Answer (score 1):

On Windows just give write permission to folder and files inside

On linux using Apache: `chown -R www-data.www-data /folder/path/app/storage`

If you are not using Apache, change the user name **www-data** to the name your web server uses.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows IIS Server machine > Explorer > right click on the storage folder and add all permisions to Everyone.